# What's the difference between Django ModelForm and models.Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am learning Django but cannot understand ModelForm ans models.Model, could anyone explain the difference between them? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/)

A `ModelForm` is a *Form* that maps closely to the fields defined in a specific *Model*. Models are defined by subclassing `models.Model`.

A `Model` is the source of information about your data. It contains the essential fields and behaviours of the data you’re storing. Generally, each model maps to a single database table. When you are developing your webapp, chances are that you’ll have forms that map closely to Django models. For this reason, Django provides a helper class that lets you create a Form class from a Django model. This helper class is the `ModelForm` class

The `ModelForm`s you create are rendered in your templates so that users can create or update the actual data that is stored in the database tables defined by your `Model`s.

For instance lets say you want to store data about articles in your web application, you would first define a model called Article like so:

in your models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

in your forms.py you would create a *modelForm* to correspond with the Article *model* you have just created.

```
from .models import Article
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'body']
```

and then in your views.py you can render your articleform:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import ArticleForm

def article_form_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    return render(request, 'article_form.html', {'form': form})
```